# html stuck to the bottom of page

Tags: html, css

```css
/* Suburban Dogma Main Stylesheet
 v1.0 10/19/2014
 Author: Bob
*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------Header Section--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#social-icons {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 top: 0.6em;
 right: 3em;
}
.soc-icon {
 margin-right: 0.3em;
}
.header {
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
     background-color: #2C2C2C;
     width: 100%;
     height: 3em;
}
#menu-logo {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 top: 0.7em;
 left: 0.3em;
}
#menu-square {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 top: 0.6em;
 left: 0.3em;
}
#menu-title {
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
 top: 0.3em;
 right: 0.6em;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #DDD;
}
#menu-logo-semi {
 display: none;
}
#menu-logo-small {
 display: none;
}
#icon-tw-dark {
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------Menu Section-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.list-menu {
 padding: 0.9em 0em 0.9em 0.5em;
}
.list-header {
 background-color: #232323;
}
.list-header p {
 padding: 0.5em 0em 0.5em 1.5em;
 color: #606060;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 80%;
}
#section-two a:hover {
 color: #18bf13
} 
#section-three a:hover {
 color: #e2e21b;
}
#section-four a:hover {
 color: #ac1db7;
}
#section-home {
 position: relative;
 left: 0.1em;
     background-image: url('../images/menu-icons/image-home.png');
     background-position: left center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding-left: 1.5em;
}
#section-one {
 position: relative;
 left: 0.1em;
     background-image: url('../images/menu-icons/image-before-blue.png');
     background-position: left center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding-left: 1.5em;
}
#section-two {
 position: relative;
 left: 0.1em;
     background-image: url('../images/menu-icons/image-before-green.png');
     background-position: left center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding-left: 1.5em;
}
#section-three {
 position: relative;
 left: 0.1em;
     background-image: url('../images/menu-icons/image-before-yellow.png');
     background-position: left center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding-left: 1.5em;
}
#section-four {
 position: relative;
 left: 0.1em;
     background-image: url('../images/menu-icons/image-before-purple.png');
     background-position: left center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding-left: 1.5em;
}
.other-section {
 padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Suburban Dogma | Magazine</title>
  
 <!--Metas-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 
 <!--Fonts----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 
 <!--Stylesheets/Scripts------------------------>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="slidebars.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive-style.css">
</head>
<body> 
 
<!--All content-->
<div id="sb-site">
 <!--Top navigation bar--------->
 <div id="header" class="header">
   <!--Logo Image---------------------------------------------------------------------------->
   <a href="/index.html"><img id="menu-logo" src="../images/logo.svg"/></a>
   <a href="/index.html"><img id="menu-logo-semi" src="../images/logo-semi.svg"/></a>
   <a href="/index.html"><img id="menu-logo-small" src="../images/logo-short.svg"/></a>
   <!--Toggle sidebar menu----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
   <a href="#" class="sb-toggle-left button left-align"><img src="../images/menu48.svg" id="menu-square" class="icon"/></a>
   <!--Menu title-------------------------------------------------------------->
   <a href="#" id="menu-title" class="sb-toggle-left button left-align">MENU</a>
   <!--Row of social media icons/links------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
   <div id="social-icons">
    <a href="#"><img id="icon-fb" class="soc-icon" src="../images/menu-icons/icon-fb-dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/menu-icons/icon-fb-color.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/menu-icons/icon-fb-dark.png'"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="icon-tw" class="soc-icon" src="../images/menu-icons/icon-tw-dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/menu-icons/icon-tw-color.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/menu-icons/icon-tw-dark.png'"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="icon-ig" class="soc-icon" src="../images/menu-icons/icon-ig-dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/menu-icons/icon-ig-color.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/menu-icons/icon-ig-dark.png'"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="icon-tu" class="soc-icon" src="../images/menu-icons/icon-tu-dark.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/menu-icons/icon-tu-color.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/menu-icons/icon-tu-dark.png'"/></a> 
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!--Add left sidebar with push control-------->
<div class="sb-slidebar sb-left sb-style-push">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li id="section-home" class="list-menu"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
   <li class="list-header"><p id="sections">SECTIONS</a></li>
   <li id="section-one" class="list-menu"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
   <li id="section-two" class="list-menu"><a href="#">Style</a></li>
   <li id="section-three" class="list-menu"><a href="#">Pop Culture</a></li>
   <li id="section-four" class="list-menu"><a href="#">Tech</a></li>
   <li class="list-header"><p id="other">OTHER</a></li>
   <li class="list-menu other-section"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   <li class="list-menu other-section"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
<!--Link to jQuery and other scripts------------------------------------------------------->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write( '<script src="jquery.min.js"><\/script>' )</script>

<!--Script to run slidebar-------------------> 
<script src="slidebars.min.js"></script>
<script>
 (function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $.slidebars();
  });
 }) (jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I finally created my header and everything on my site but now when I try to add content into the body it gets stuck at the very bottom of the page like a footer.
Could anyone give me some insight on this?
Also when I try to add content after my header div and before my site div, it doesn't show anything.

I used a third party jQuery plugin but I followed the usage correctly so that shouldn't be affecting it but here is a refrence:

[My website in progress with the html and css](http://workinprogress.suburbandogma.com)

[My menu usage guide in case you want to check the syntax on it](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/usage.php)

ANY help would be greatly appreciated as I am now stuck on this and I just cant get any html to show up correctly after the navigation menu

If you are trying the code out yourself, you can just skip past the reset.css and responsive.css as those are self-explanatory.

Comment: Please post your code. As soon as the issue is solved, this question becomes obsolete.

Comment: yeah post code or at least post content in the body on your current site so we can identify the issue, a header on a blank page isnt going to help

Comment: Well there's quite a bit of code I thought people would just inspect source code.

Comment: We can inspect the source but there is nothing to inspect, add content to your site so we can see the issue that you are talking about

Comment: I have added 4 strips of text to all the places that I could add content to the body and you can now see it live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple. Your header is set to `position: fixed` so when you add content below the header its actually behind it because `fixed` breaks the element out of the flow of the document. As for the text at the bottom. You have `min-height: 518px` on `#sb-site`. So if you put content below `#sb-site` (and not in it) its going to be `518px` below it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do you recommend I keep the header stuck to the top then?

Comment: you're doing the right thing, `position: fixed` is correct it you want it to always be there. What you need to do is push your content below the header. You could use `padding`. Your header is `48px` tall so you could add a `div` container and set the top padding to `48px`. Essentially you need to have your content start below the header's height if that makes sense.